# QueryString with ASP.NET MVC 6 Anchor Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create the following html output:

```
<a href="account/register?provider=1">Register</a>
```

How can I accomplish this with ASP.NET MVC 6 anchor tag helper?  It seems that there is no option for the query string part.  I want to use

```
<a asp-action="Register" asp-controller="Account">Register</a>
```

but where do I put "provider=1"?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Did you try the `asp-route-*` attribute:

```
<a asp-action="Register" 
   asp-controller="Account"
   asp-route-provider="1">
    Register
</a>
```

Comment: This is MAGIC. Thanks Darin.

Comment: Magic indeed. Great.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't believe this to be the right answer. This works fine for route parameters but if it is tagged as a `[FromQuery]` parameter on the argument of the controller method signature it does not get passed.

Comment: @Shawn, I have a `[FromQuery]` parameter on my action method, and this answer worked for me. I'm doing this: `<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-embedded="true">Cancel</a>` which gives me `https://sitename/home/index?embedded=true`.

Comment: This actually works, but I had to restart the app to make it work. Otherwise, the link wasn't generated with a proper query string.